# ESP32 crashes with Micropython with simple test program

Tags: esp32, micropython

Here is a simple Micropython program that I wrote to test my ESP32 Vroom32 board. It crashes after several minutes. I got about 38000 counts out of it.

```
from time import sleep

n = 0
while 1:
    print(n)
    n += 1

    sleep(0.02)
```

Here is the code that I'm using to read it.

```
import serial, serial.tools.list_ports
import time

def find_port():  #Finds which port the arduino is plugged into
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if "EA60" in p[2]:
            return(p[0])
usbport = find_port()
ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 115200) #setup serial
while 1:      
    try:  
        data = ser.readline()
        ser.flushInput()
        data = data.strip().decode()
        print(data) 
        time.sleep(0.02)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I've tried different things such as blinking the LED and slowing down the timing to 0.2 seconds. After doing those two things it ran about 8 hours and then crashed. When it crashed. I had to unplug the device and plug it back in and restart the python program on the computer before it would run again. Simply resetting the device did not work. Also, after I added the LED blink code (not included in the above example) the LED kept blinking the entire time. It was like it was still running, but not communicating.

New micropython code that blinks:

```
from time import sleep
from machine import Pin
n = 0
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
while 1:        
    print(n)        
    n += 1
    led.value(not led.value())
    sleep(0.2)
```

Update:

Last night I added some code to try to catch the error. The board still crashed and no error file was created.

```
New main.py
from time import sleep
from machine import Pin
n = 0
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
while 1:
    try:
        led.value(not led.value())
        n += 1
        print(n)
        sleep(0.2)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ESP32: ", e)
```

New desktop script:

```
import serial, serial.tools.list_ports
import time

def find_port():  #Finds which port the arduino is plugged into
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if "EA60" in p[2]:
            return(p[0])
usbport = find_port()
ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 115200, timeout=10) #setup serial
while 1:      
    try:  
        data = ser.readline()
        ser.flushInput()
        data = data.strip().decode()
        print(data) 
        if "ESP32" in data:
            with open("errors.txt", "a") as f:
                err = data + "\n"
                f.write(err)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Is this running on the ESP32, or on a PC that is connected to it? What are the symptoms of the crash?

Comment: @nekomatic My bad. I edited my question and added the devices code.

Comment: So the MicroPython code keeps running (as shown by the LED blinking) but you're no longer receiving data at the PC end, and the code at the PC end doesn't get any errors? I don't know but some random ideas: is the ESP32 mounted as a flash drive while you're doing this? Does your ESP32 have UART pins that you could use to send the data to a separate USB-serial adapter on the PC? If you don't get anywhere I would take this to the forum at micropython.org.